# How to install a module to one of many pythons in Fedora 20

Tags: python, module

I have on my Fedora 20 additionally to 2.7 a python3.6 version installed.
When I run a script with the 3.6 version it's missing the requests module.
When I try to install it with the pip command it says it's already there.
So, how can I install this module in python3.6?

Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: the easiest way is to use virtualenvs... but that is way beyond the scope of stack overflow ... try something like `/usr/share/lib/python36/python -m pip install some_package`  (assuming pip is installed for the version you are using)

Comment: @Joran Beasley:
Thanks for answering!
When I run
/usr/local/bin/python3.6 -m pip install requests
I get:
/usr/local/bin/python3.6: No module named pip
also the same with pip3, pip36 or pip3.6
whereis pip:
pip: /usr/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip2.7 - Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Check if pip36 or more likely pip3 is a function you can run. Often times the pip command corresponds to the first installed python version, so if you install one later it gets the suffix according to its version. If that is the case then you'll want to do pip36 (pip3) install moduleXYZ.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
I have pip, pip2 and pip2.7 but also a python3-pip in /usr/bin available.
When I run python3-pip I get:
Usage:   
  pip <command> [options]...
And when I run:
python[3.6|3] -m python3-pip install requests it says:
No module named python3-pip

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty answer is
For python2,x install any package using `pip install requests`
For python 3.x install any package using `pip3 install requests`
If you get error during pip3 please run `sudo dnf install python3-pip`

But the right way is to do it using Virtual Environment in fedona

For py3.4+

```
$ python3.5 -m venv env  # create the virtualenv
$ . env/bin/activate  # activate it
(env)$ python -m pip install requests  # install a package with pip
```

For py2.x, 3.x

```
$ dnf install python-virtualenv  # install the necessary tool
$ virtualenv --python /usr/bin/python2.7 env  # create the virtualenv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7
New python executable in env/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
$ . env/bin/activate  # activate it
(env)$ python -m pip install requests  # install a package with pip
```

[Refrence](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/python/multiple-pythons.html)

Comment: Many thanks @Aki003:

python3.6 -m venv env, it says:
 Error: Command '['/sw/Python-3.6.1/env/bin/env/bin/python3.6', '-Im', 
 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

dnf install python-virtualenv, 
        installed:  python-virtualenv.noarch 12.0.7-1.fc20

virtualenv --python /usr/bin/python3.6 env,
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 17, in <module>
     import zlib
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'